# Number of values of $a$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that both the roots of the equation $$x^2+ax+2016=0$$ are positive even integers.The question is to find out the number of possible values of $a$

Since the coefficient of $x^2>0$ it is a upward parabola.Now since at $x=0,y=2016$ so I thought  that no such value of $a$ is possible.However the answer key gives gives it as$12$ .Please help me in this regard.Thanks.

Comment: `thought that no such value of a is possible` Correction: no *positive* value of $a$ is possible. Hint: the product of those two positive even integers must be $2016 = 32\cdot 9 \cdot 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f(x) = x^2+ax+2016=0$

Let $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)=0$ be the roots of $f(x)$

Then $f(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta=0$

Comparing coefficients we get:

$-(\alpha+\beta)=a$

$\alpha\beta=2016$

Now we consider the prime factorisation of $2016=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot 7$

We are given from the question that both the roots are positive even integers - so they both must have at least $1$ factor of $2$.

Then we have the following distinct possibilities:

$(1)\quad\alpha = 2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 7,\quad\beta =2 $

$(2)\quad\alpha = 2^4\cdot 3^2,\quad \beta = 2\cdot 7$

$(3)\quad\alpha = 2^4\cdot 3,\quad\beta = 2\cdot3\cdot 7$

$(4)\quad\alpha = 2^4\cdot 7,\quad\beta=2^4\cdot 3^2$

$(5)\quad\alpha = 2^4\cdot 3\cdot 7,\quad\beta=2\cdot 3$

$(6)\quad\alpha = 2^4,\quad\beta=2\cdot 3^2\cdot 7$

$(7)\quad\alpha = 2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 7,\quad \beta = 2^2$

$(8)\quad\alpha = 2^3\cdot 3^2,\quad\beta=2^2\cdot 7$

$(9)\quad\alpha = 2^3\cdot 3,\quad \beta = 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 7$

$(10)\quad\alpha = 2^3\cdot 7,\quad \beta=2^2\cdot 3^2$

$(11)\quad\alpha = 2^3\cdot 3\cdot 7,\quad\beta= 2^2\cdot 3$

$(12)\quad\alpha = 2^3,\quad\beta=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 7$

All you need to do is show that the sum each of these combinations is different, and therefore the total possible values of $a$ is $12$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Remember the sum-product theorem: if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are roots of $\alpha x^2+bx+c$, then:

$$x_1+x_2=-\frac{b}{\alpha}$$
$$x_1\times x_2=\frac{c}{\alpha}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1$, $x_2$ be roots of equation. You have $x_1+x_2 = -a$, then $a < 0$.

You have $x_1x_2 = 2016 = 32\times 9\times 7$. If $x_i$ are positive even integers, then you can take all possibilites cases, for example: $(14,144)$, then $a = -158$.

Answer (score 0):

(x-2m)(x-2n) = your function = 0.

Multiply this out, and you'll end up with mn = -504, and a = -2(m+n).

Count up all the ways that you can come up with integers m and n such that mn = -504 AND that yield a distinct a.

Answer (score 0):

Well think about what happens when $x=0$, you are plugging in zero for every $x$ in the equation.

$f(0) = (0)^2 + a(0) + 2016$

$f(0) = 0 + 0 + 2016$

$f(0) = 2016$

Now to figure out what $a$ is...

$a$ can be any two factors of $2016$ added together.

ie: $2$ and $1008$ or conversely, $-2$ and $-1008$ since two negatives multiplied together are positive

add these up and you get your $a$

$a = 1010$  or $a = -1010$ or any other addition of two factors